# importing from yfinance rounds data

Tags: python, numpy, alpha-vantage, yfinance

I have been hitting my head against a wall here for the last couple of hours, I'm not that familiar with python and I'm trying to import historical data from Yahoo finance.

I've got it set up to import the data I want, but ran into a problem with the actual data, when trying to add some technical indicators. I saw that the data was rounded making the low and high price exactly the same, making it useless for my project unless I can resolve this.

I have tried using a alternative to yfinance namely alpha vantage, but ran into the same problem, I tried converting the field to a float but it also gave me the same values just with a lot of zero's at the back.

I suspect that its the way I'm importing the data or maybe the way my spider is set up. the code below is how I import the data,

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 import yfinance as yf
 from alpha_vantage.foreignexchange import ForeignExchange

 api_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

 data = yf.download(tickers='EURUSD=X', period='7d', interval='1m', rounding ="True")
 data3 = data.to_numpy()

 fx =ForeignExchange(key=api_key, output_format="pandas")
 data_FX, meta_data_FX = fx.get_currency_exchange_intraday(from_symbol="EUR", to_symbol = "USD",interval="1min", outputsize = "full")
```

This is the way the data is added to the dataset

```
Datetime                     Open    High     Low   Close Adj Close Volume
2021-01-15 00:00:00+00:00   1.2154  1.2154  1.2154  1.2154  1.2154  0
2021-01-15 00:01:00+00:00   1.2157  1.2157  1.2157  1.2157  1.2157  0
2021-01-15 00:02:00+00:00   1.2155  1.2155  1.2155  1.2155  1.2155  0
2021-01-15 00:03:00+00:00   1.2157  1.2157  1.2157  1.2157  1.2157  0
2021-01-15 00:04:00+00:00   1.2158  1.2158  1.2158  1.2158  1.2158  0
2021-01-15 00:05:00+00:00   1.2158  1.2158  1.2158  1.2158  1.2158  0
2021-01-15 00:06:00+00:00   1.2158  1.2158  1.2158  1.2158  1.2158  0
2021-01-15 00:07:00+00:00   1.2161  1.2161  1.2161  1.2161  1.2161  0
```

Is this spider that needs to be adjusted, or is there a better/correct way to import the data

Comment: Please always include tags for major libraries like NumPy and Pandas if you are using them, as described in the [tag:python] tag wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why yfinance has the same high and low values, but if you set yfinance to 1 hour intervals, the high and low values will be different, so if you adjust the alpha side to 1 hour, you can handle it. If the specification requires 1 minute intervals, then this answer is useless.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

data = yf.download(tickers='EURUSD=X', period='7d', interval='1h', rounding ="True")
data3 = data.to_numpy()

    Open    High    Low     Close   Adj Close   Volume
Date                        
2021-01-18  1.2070  1.2085  1.2069  1.2079  1.2079  0
2021-01-18  1.2080  1.2085  1.2076  1.2082  1.2082  0
2021-01-18  1.2085  1.2089  1.2080  1.2086  1.2086  0
2021-01-18  1.2086  1.2088  1.2074  1.2079  1.2079  0
2021-01-18  1.2077  1.2080  1.2070  1.2073  1.2073  0
...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2021-01-25  1.2145  1.2148  1.2142  1.2146  1.2146  0
2021-01-26  1.2145  1.2149  1.2137  1.2139  1.2139  0
2021-01-26  1.2139  1.2151  1.2139  1.2149  1.2149  0
2021-01-26  1.2149  1.2154  1.2149  1.2149  1.2149  0
2021-01-26  1.2148  1.2148  1.2148  1.2148  1.2148  0

146 rows × 6 columns

from alpha_vantage.foreignexchange import ForeignExchange

with open('./alpha_vantage_api_key.txt') as f:
    api_key = f.read()

fx =ForeignExchange(key=api_key, output_format="pandas")
data_FX, meta_data_FX = fx.get_currency_exchange_intraday(from_symbol="EUR", to_symbol = "USD", interval="60min", outputsize = "full")

    1. open     2. high     3. low  4. close
date                
2021-01-26 03:00:00     1.2145  1.2146  1.2143  1.2145
2021-01-26 02:00:00     1.2134  1.2146  1.2132  1.2145
2021-01-26 01:00:00     1.2143  1.2143  1.2131  1.2134
2021-01-26 00:00:00     1.2142  1.2145  1.2140  1.2143
2021-01-25 23:00:00     1.2137  1.2145  1.2134  1.2142
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2020-11-30 20:00:00     1.1952  1.1952  1.1940  1.1947
2020-11-30 19:00:00     1.1954  1.1960  1.1949  1.1952
2020-11-30 18:00:00     1.1947  1.1955  1.1940  1.1954
2020-11-30 17:00:00     1.1964  1.1965  1.1941  1.1948
2020-11-30 16:00:00     1.1994  1.2003  1.1954  1.1964
```

Answer (score 0):

You have explicitly asked yf to round the numbers.
data = yf.download(tickers='EURUSD=X', period='7d', interval='1h', rounding ="True")

Use rounding="False".

I am a bit puzzled that you're still getting four digits and not two, but that may be a change since the question was posted two years ago. If it were four, the feature would be far more useful for backtesting calculations.